# Bulk Copying Error In Postgres database, while using Copy syntax to import CSV files into tables

Tags: postgresql, psql, sqlbulkcopy, postgresql-copy

```
CREATE TABLE parts (
    id integer,
    description character varying,
    code character varying,
    manufacturer_id  integer
);

CREATE TABLE  locations (
    id integer,
    part_id integer,
    location varchar(3),
    qty integer
);

create table manufacturers (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar
);

create table reorder_options (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  part_id integer,
  price_usd numeric(8,2),
  quantity integer
);
```

I'm trying to copy files into some table that I've created above, it is poping permission denied

> I've tried these codes

```
 copy parts FROM 'C:\Users\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\parts.csv' delimiter ',' NULL AS 'NULL' csv header;
 copy locations FROM 'C:\Users\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\locations.csv' delimiter ',' NULL AS 'NULL' csv header
 copy manufacturers FROM 'C:\Users\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\manufacturers.csv' delimiter ',' NULL AS 'NULL' csv header
 copy reorder_options FROM 'C:\Users\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\reorder_options.csv' delimiter ',' NULL AS 'NULL' csv header
```

I researched in stack overflow, some people suggested use \copy instead of copy, I tried same

```
 \copy parts FROM 'C:\Users\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\parts.csv' delimiter ',' NULL AS 'NULL' csv header;
 \copy locations FROM 'C:\Users\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\locations.csv' delimiter ',' NULL AS 'NULL' csv header
 \copy manufacturers FROM 'C:\Users\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\manufacturers.csv' delimiter ',' NULL AS 'NULL' csv header
 \copy reorder_options FROM 'C:\Users\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\XXXXX\reorder_options.csv' delimiter ',' NULL AS 'NULL' csv header
```

It is throwing syntax error at or near ''

Comment: And what is the content of your csv-files? Encoding?

Comment: @AlexYu  'utf-8', why syntax error at or near '\'

Comment: I don't see any `"` in your commands. So I expect that they comes from csv. And I suppose that your first variant is correct and you need to check accout that you trying to use.

Comment: @AlexYu thats a typing mistake instead of ",real error message is this  "syntax error at or near '/' ".